# How to make `template<> struct fmt::formatter<Foo>` friend of Foo

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, fmt

I have a class `Foo` with a private member `x`, and I want to be able to print instances of `Foo` via `fmt::print`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/dqxh3Mb4s)

```cpp
#include <fmt/format.h>

class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(int i) : x{i} {}
private:
    int x{};
};

template<>
struct fmt::formatter<Foo> {
    template<typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx) {
        return ctx.begin();
    }

    template<typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const Foo& foo, FormatContext& ctx) {
        return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", foo.x);
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo{5};
    fmt::print("{}", foo);
}
```

The code above has the problem of trying to access the private member `Foo::x`.

```
<source>:19:52: error: 'int Foo::x' is private within this context
   19 |         return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", foo.x);
      |                                                ~~~~^
```

I have evaluated a few options:

1. Implement a `Foo::to_string` method (and use it from `format`).
   This is an easy option, but I wouldn't like `format` to need use `to_string`; I would prefer it could operate directly on `x`.
2. Provide a `get_x` accessor (and use it from `format`).
   This is also an easy option. `format` would be operating on `x`. However, I understand that, many times, you don't want to provide accessors for your private data.
3. Make `template<> struct fmt::formatter<Foo>` a friend of `Foo`.
   This is the option I would really go for, only that I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 5):

Add `friend struct fmt::formatter<Foo>` within `Foo`:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/r3nbnxv6W)

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(int i) : x{i} {}
private:
    int x{};

    friend struct fmt::formatter<Foo>;
};
```